# Lollipop Encryption fails: Cannot open footer file /efs/metadata

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have a Galaxy Note GT-N7000 and I've just flashed [Paranoid Android v5.1.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note/development/rom-paranoid-android-lollipop-t3145459) I cleared the Dalvik cache and did a factory reset before flashing. Everything works well, except Android refuses to encrypt my device. Going into Settings -> Security -> Encrypt phone I press the "Encrypt" button. The phone displays a droid logo and reboots after about 5 seconds. Obviously, my phone has not been encrypted, so what went wrong?

Hooked up the phone to my laptop and started adb. Logcat says:

> E/Cryptfs ( 1913): Cannot open footer file /efs/metadata for get
>   E/Cryptfs ( 1913): Cannot open footer file /efs/metadata for put
>   E/Cryptfs ( 1913): Error writing the key to the end of the partition
>   E/Cryptfs ( 1913): Error enabling encryption after framework
>   is shutdown, no data changed, restarting system

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

My phone is rooted. Pattern lock is set. The device was fully charged and connected to a power source via USB.

This guy seems to have the same problem as me:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60916406&postcount=6136

I think the problem is caused by the same thing since my ROM is based on CM12.